# Convert my android dimen file into others for different densities

Tags: android, xml, dimensions

I have a single dimen file in an app and I'm looking into converting it into all the necessary variations (hdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi, and so on). My problem is that I haven't found a good guide explaining how to do this. to take a dp and get the equivalente for all these variants.

Does anyone know what kind of math I have to use? Is there some tool for it?

Answer (score 0):

The point of dpi is not to do that.  1 dpi- 1/160th of an inch in any density.  That's why they're density independent.  The reason you'd change them is if you want to change the size of something in physical real estate.  And you wouldn't do that by density, you'd do it by screen size-  for example max an image bigger on a tablet because you have more room to fill.